# MVC to data layer to dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My solution has the following projects:

- **Logan.Web.DBContext** This is where the DbContext for the tables are defined along with relationships, etc
- **Logan.Web.DBObjects** This is where classes are defined for the tables. These contain the properties that will be used in the application
- **Logan.Web.Data** This is the data layer that the MVC application will use to interact with the above
- **LoganMVC** The actual MVC website

I'm starting with logic for CRUD actions involving user records so I have the following already coded:

**DB Context**

```
namespace Logan.Web.DBContext
{
    public class UserDBContext : LoganDBBaseObject<User>
    {
        private static WebDBContext db = new WebDBContext();

        public UserDBContext()
            : base()
        {
            Property(p => p.Username)
                .HasColumnName("sUsername")
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(p => p.EmailAddress)
                .HasColumnName("sEmailAddress")
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(p => p.Password)
                .HasColumnName("sPassword")
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(p => p.Biography)
                .HasColumnName("sBiography")
                .HasColumnType("text");

            HasRequired(r => r.Role)
                .WithMany(m => m.Users)
                .Map(x => x.MapKey("fkRoleID"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            ToTable("Users");

        }
    }
}
```

**Class Definition**

```
namespace Logan.Web.Objects
{
    public class User : LoganBaseObject<User>
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Username = String.Empty;
            EmailAddress = String.Empty;
            Password = String.Empty;
            Biography = String.Empty;
            Articles = new List<Article>();
        }
    }
}
```

**CRUD Functionality**

```
namespace Logan.Web.Data
{
    public class WebUser
    {
        WebDBContext db = new WebDBContext();

        public List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return db.Users.Include(x => x.Role).ToList();
        }
}
```

I'm having trouble trying to tie this code into MVC. I understand I'd probably do it in the Model, but I don't get how this tells the View whats what and how to tell the Database what the View said when I want to manipulate data.

All I've managed to do so far is this:

```
    // controller
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserModel u = new UserModel();
        var users = u.GetUsers();

        return View(users);
    }

    // model
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        WebUser u = new WebUser();
        return u.GetUsers();
    }
```

How could use this structure to create write/update/delete functions or to get a record by it's Primary Key?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your WebUser class to include methods for those operations.

You need:

```
public User GetUser(string userName)

public User CreateUser(User user)

public User UpdateUser(User user)

public bool DeleteUser(string userName)
```

Although, you will likely run into problems naming a class `User` because it is reserved by the MVC framework.

Comment: The User class exists in an entirely different namespace so if I have any problems, I'll just reference the fully qualified namespace.

Comment: Yep, I know, but it just becomes a pain.